# Get information from another website using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-get-contents

I need a method to remove from the CyanogenMod website Downloads area all supported models using PHP, and be able to separate model information in a variable object `($variable->Object;)`.

I think it's possible, removing the HTML information, but have no idea where to start ...

The html follows this pattern.
the word VENDOR in uppercase would be the manufacturer's name
lowercase no use is used to call css function that manufacturer

```
<li id="vendor_VENDOR">
<span> VENDOR </span>
</li>
<ul class = "nav-list nav">
<li id="device_DEVICE MODEL NUMBER"> <a href="javascript: void (0)" onclick="navigate_device ('DEVICE MODEL NUMBER');" class="device"><span> Device name (device model number)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The website: http://download.cyanogenmod.org/

Comment: you can start learning WEB SCRAPING with phpQuery library

Comment: Be careful though, as their [terms of use](https://cyngn.com/legal/terms-of-use) explicitly state that `you agree not to access, monitor or copy any element of the Cyanogen Services using a robot, spider, scraper or other automated means or manual process without our express written permission.` So what you want to do is strictly speaking illegal (if you don't have the written permission that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

It is called [`Web Scrapping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) there are many `API` in different languages to do that. A lof of them use a css like selector system like jQuery to navigate throgh the HTML Document.

I have been doing that but with Java but there are many PHP solutions.
Look at this [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best I ever seen is **[Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**!!! Seems jQuery, but it's PHP! ;)